# Логика приложения, использование кэша

Tags: java, android, база-данных, kotlin

Я задался вопросом, как правильно хранить кэш ? Тоесть я хочу услышать предложение как лучше всего его хранить.
Например я думаю так:
Качаем информацию, сохраняем в кэш.
Если пользователь переключается опять во view с информацией которая загружается с интернета, то выдаём имеющуюся, с проверкой сколько прошло времени.
Потом есть проблема со хранением ее. Потому что, новая информация приходит, но старая не удаляется, и тут появляется логический вопрос. Удалять ее когда качаем новую информацию, через какое время. Или же обнулять ее каждый день ? Хотелось бы услышать предложение. Как вы реализовываете хранение кэша.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос зависит от постановки задачи, которую Вы пытаетесь решить.

В общем случае можно обновлять данные либо по мере их устаревания (отслеживать актуальность по времени) либо периодически.

> новая информация приходит, но старая не удаляется

Разумеется, устаревшие данные нужно удалять после загрузки новых.

Comment: Задача в том, что бы качать лист информации о обновдении книг(примерное время обновлении глав, 20 минут). Вот и думаю, если натыкать так 10 раз, база уже 10 мб, удалять ее после прохождения времени или после 5 вызовов.

Comment: @ЕгорГлухов, лично я бы в таком случае, просто "прошёлся" по кэшу и заменил старые данные на новые, если информация о книге обновилась. Если нет, оставил запись о книге как есть.

Comment: Там список обновляется, редко когда попадаются такие же книги.